# Accessing locally hosted webservice from my iPhone or Blackberry

Tags: ios, web-services, rest, blackberry

How can I connect to my locally hosted restful service from my iPhone/Blackberry?

Comment: This is two distinct questions. Please ask separately for ios and BlackBerry.

Comment: @MichaelDonohue For iOS, I have figured it out. Can you please explain me for Blackberry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to install BlackBerry simulator (with MDS simulator) and XAMPP (or Tomcat/JBOSS whatever, depending on your webservice implementation).

Modify hosts (on Windows computer) like that:

```
127.0.0.1    www.mycustomwebservice.com
```

Than launch your webservice implementation server, launch MDS simulator that comes with BlackBerry simulator and launch BlackBerry simulator with your application.

Your webservice will be availabe for your application running on simulator by this address:  `www.mycustomwebservice.com`